# Tiptap2 floating menu giving me an error in vue 3 with script setup

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-script-setup, tiptap

I'm just following the tiptap docs trying to implement a floating menu in vue 3. Im using script setup and im not sure if thats the issue, but in either case im struggling to get this to work. The floating menu doesnt render.

Can't figure out why? And there doesnt seem to be much help to find elsewhere. I even tried chatGPT but all its answers where absurd. Probably because it doesnt seem to do well with vue 3 scrip setup.

I'll provide a stackblitz of the issue and a link to the docs to make it as easy as possible to investigate. Thanks for any suggestions.

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-tedyxp?file=src/App.vue)

[docs](https://tiptap.dev/api/extensions/floating-menu)

Comment: You don't need to change the provided Options API code into Composition API. You can copy/paste the provided code into an SFC (separate `.vue` file) and then import that file wherever you want to use it. [Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-w9yqsy?file=src%2FApp.vue,src%2FEditor.vue). Since writing that code into Composition API syntax is totally optional, and you seem to struggle with it, why are you doing it?

Comment: Because Im going to be spending a considerable time inside this component writing custom logic, and I would like to keep it all composition API anyhow. And on top of that Vue Vapor mode is coming soon and it will allow me to drop the vdom but vapor components can only do composition api and I need all components to be vaport components in order to drop the vdom.

There has to be a way to make this work in composition API and im reaching for help to figure that out and to make it easier for otherts to do the same. Source for vaport mode claims: https://blog.vuejs.org/posts/2022-year-in-review

Comment: Also part of this is that if it turns out that im not the one making a mistake, its just plainly giving me an error because im using the composition api then the right course of action would be the submit an issue on the tiptap2 github.

Comment: Anything written in Composition API can be written in Options API and vice-versa. They're completely translatable into each other, so no, using Composition API can't be the reason why something does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem. When using vue3 you should import FloatingMenu from '@tiptap/vue-3' and not from the regular '@tiptap/extension-floating-menu.' Hope this post is helpfull for anyone else making this same mistake. Heres the working example: [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue3-script-setup-with-vite-cgykmk?file=src%2FApp.vue)